# How do I fix Hardware error? Kubuntu 22.04 RTX 4070 TI

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, kubuntu, crash

I am running a RTX 4070TI and an I7-9700k with a Dualboot one being Windows and the other is Kubuntu 22.04.

Ever since I installed the RTX 4070TI and installed its drivers my Kubuntu freezes or shuts down on random occasions.

My nvidia-driver version is: 525.85.05

And today after running nvidia-smi I got following error message after about 30 seconds:

```
mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 5: Machine Check Exception 5 Bank 0: b200000000030005
mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 33:<0000000000f6b620>
mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 13276948cb2
mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR: 0:906ed TIME 1678618359 SOCKET 0 APIC a micronode f4
mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check: Processor context corrupt
Kernal panic - not syncing: Fatal machine check 
Kernal Offset: 0x2fc00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff81000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
```

Can anyone give me advice on how to continue to troubleshoot and fix my issues.

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you get any problems in windows?

Comment: No Windows runs completely stable and fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS crashes with mce related error messages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293734/ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-crashes-with-mce-related-error-messages)

Comment: Currently trying following solution, I will report back if its successful: https://cloudlinux.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014017379-Kernel-panic-not-syncing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution seemed to resolve the issue:

https://cloudlinux.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014017379-Kernel-panic-not-syncing